# Real time update of marker without loading web page loading updated coordinates from a text file Google maps Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My code is working when I load my page for the first time, but I want to update marker position by reading coordinates from a text file without loading map again and again. I have used on function called `setInterval(myFunction, 10000);` but it doesn't work for me. It load map again and again and also slow down after few updates.

My problem is that I want real time location updates on web page, as Arduino GPS Tracker will update coordinates on server in a text file i.e `dob.txt` file contents are as `33.729388199999995, 75.0931461`. These coordinates will be updated within in few seconds and need to show in map without loading map again.
Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var im = 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/google-location-icon-Location_marker_pin_map_gps.png';

var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png',
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
    new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));



loadFile('dob.txt');

function loadFile(uri) {
    r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('GET', uri, true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (r.readyState == 4) {
            lines = r.responseText.split("\n");
            if (lines) {

                initialize(lines);
            }
        }
    }
    r.send(null);
    setInterval(loadFile, 5000);
} //loadFile Ends here



function initialize() {

    // Create the map.

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        segments = lines[0].split(',');
        lat = segments[0];
        lng = segments[1];


    } // for loop Ends


    point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    mapOptionss = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: point,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptionss);



    //Marker Starts
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point, //new google.maps.LatLng(33.729388199999995, 75.0931461),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        title: "My place"

    });
    //Marker Ends here

    marker.setMap(map);


}; //initialize method End

function setTime() {

    setInterval(loadFile, 1000); //setInterval End

}

function setUpdate() {

    ln = r.responseText.split("\n");
    for (var a = 0; a < ln.length; a++) {
        var data = ln[a].split(',');
        var latt = data[0];
        var lngg = data[1];
    }
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latt, lngg));
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(latt, lngg));
    marker.setMap(map);
    setInterval(setUpdate, 1000);

}
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

1 - When you're creating markers, store them in an array

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker( ... );    
  markers.push( marker );
```

2 - When you want to refresh, use the array to delete the previous markers

```
function deleteMarkers() {
     markers.forEach( function ( marker ) {
       marker.setMap( null );
     } ); 
     markers = [];
}
```

BTW, I think you forgot to declare your `marker` variable.

Comment: I have declared global marker. And I need to access new coordinates from my text file `dob.txt` without loading page or loading map. Just need to update marker position with new coordinates from that text file. You can use Ajax or jQuery to fix my issue

Comment: OK, if you create a global `markers` array, the solution I've offered should do that for you, did you try it ?

Comment: Yes I have tried. But big problem is to get updated data from text file using AJax after the page is loaded, for new coordinates.

Comment: You should first init the map, then populate it with a request, and the `setInterval` should be in the request callback, just calling the request + update again and not the map init.